# AADB2C90085 error every time user is redirected to applicaiton

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-msal, msal.js, msal-angular

We are using custom policies for user flow for our app. Every time when user completes the flow, they are redirected back to /setting page from where the policy was actually triggered. However, every time user is redirected after the flow, I get `ServerError: invalid_grant: undefined - [undefined]: AADB2C90085: The service has encountered an internal error. Please reauthenticate and try again.` Although we are catching the error that results in unexpected behavior for some other flows where we want to logout the user after they have completed the flow.

```
function b2cFactory(config: B2cConfig): IPublicClientApplication {
  return new PublicClientApplication({
    auth: {
      clientId: config.clientId,
      authority: config.authorities.signUpSignIn,
      redirectUri: window.origin,
      postLogoutRedirectUri: window.origin,
      knownAuthorities: [config.authorityDomain]
    },
    cache: {
      cacheLocation: BrowserCacheLocation.LocalStorage,
      storeAuthStateInCookie: false
    },
    system: {
      loggerOptions: {
        // eslint-disable-next-line ban/ban, no-console
        loggerCallback: (level, message) => console.log(message),
        logLevel: config.logLevel,
        piiLoggingEnabled: false
      }
    }
  });
}
```

And guard configuration

```
export function b2cGuardFactory(): MsalGuardConfiguration {
      return {
        interactionType: InteractionType.Redirect,
        loginFailedRoute: `${window.origin}/error/B2C_USER_LOGIN_FAILED/1`
      };
    }
```

the b2c service in question

```
init() {
     this.msalBroadcastService.msalSubject$.subscribe((event: EventMessage) => {
  switch (event.eventType) {
    case EventType.ACQUIRE_TOKEN_SUCCESS:
      this._tokenSubject.next((event.payload as AuthenticationResult)?.accessToken);
      break;
    case EventType.HANDLE_REDIRECT_END:
      this.checkAndSetActiveAccount();
      break;
    case EventType.SSO_SILENT_FAILURE:
      // Sso session is expired but jwt can be still valid.
      this._ssoSessionExpired = true;
      break;
    default:
      if (event.error) {
        if (event.error.message?.indexOf('AADB2C90091') > -1) {
          this.window.location.replace('/settings');
        } else {
          console.error(event.error);
        }
      }
  }
});
```

So when the following function is triggered, and user completes the flow and is redirected to app, the error block above catches the error and blocks the logout logic.

```
  changeEmail() {
    // Redirect the user to ProfileEdit policy
    this.authService.loginRedirect({
      extraQueryParameters: {
        p: 'B2C_1A_PROFILEEDIT'
      },
      scopes: OIDC_DEFAULT_SCOPES,
    }).subscribe(() => this.logout());
  }
```